# Laravel 5 - Elixir - Less compilation error

Tags: laravel, less, laravel-5, gulp, laravel-elixir

I've been trying to compile two less files using Laravel's elixir.
In my gulpfile.js 'm doing :

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.less([
    'app.less',
    'soul.less'
  ]);
});
```

After running gulp, 'm only able to generate ***app.css*** and **app.css.map** in my 'public/css/' directory. 
But i am not able to find the ***soul.css*** and **soul.css.map**. When i open a page with ***soul.css*** linked, the styles are being applied but the soul.css file cannot be found.

Any fix ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Laravel 5.1 has been released you need to set the output path for files otherwise they will get combined by default.

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.less('app.less', 'public/css/app.css')
     .less('soul.less', 'public/css/soul.css');
});
```